# Creating a loop within an if/else statement

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

I'm in the early stages in learning Ruby and ran into an issue when trying to create a conditional statement for one of my programs. I basically wanted it to loop back and grab a fresh input value if the orignal didn't meet the criteria of the first two conditionals.

So for example:

```
puts "Choose either the 'red' or 'blue' pill"

choice = gets.to_s.downcase.chomp

if choice == red
    puts "Fasten your seatbelt dorothy 'cause kansas is going bye-bye" 
elsif choice == "blue"
   puts "The story ends, you wake up in your bed and believe whatever you want to believe"
else
    puts "You have to choose one"
end
```

Comment: Is `red` a variable? If not, `choice == red` will fail. It's important your source code be runnable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another common construct:

```
loop do
  puts "Choose either an 'upper' or a 'downer'"

  case gets.downcase.chomp
  when "upper"
    puts "Fasten your seatbelt dorothy 'cause kansas is going bye-bye"
    break 
  when "downer"
    puts "The story ends, you wake up and believe whatever you want to believe"
    break
  else
    puts "You have to choose one"
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice use-case of using `#loop` here. But `gets.to_s.downcase.chomp` can be written as `gets.downcase.chomp`.

Comment: Thanks, @Arup, I just blindly cut-and-pasted.  Shame on me!  Will fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
begin
  puts "Choose either the 'red' or 'blue' pill"
  choice = gets.to_s.downcase.chomp

  if choice == "red"
    puts "Fasten your seatbelt dorothy 'cause kansas is going bye-bye" 
  elsif choice == "blue"
    puts "The story ends, you wake up in your bed and believe whatever you want to believe"
  else
    puts "You have to choose one"
    choice = "invalid"
  end
end while(choice == "invalid")
```

console output:

```
Choose either the 'red' or 'blue' pill
#empty input
You have to choose one
Choose either the 'red' or 'blue' pill
red
Fasten your seatbelt dorothy 'cause kansas is going bye-bye
 => nil
```

Comment: There is no such method as `String#blank?`. Even if there was, this doesn't work right.

Comment: `blank?` is a rails thing.

Comment: @DGM yes, blank? is rails. I changed it.

Comment: I see what you did. What if I said "green"? Having the user input a value not listed is what I was looking for.

Comment: add `choice = nil` under `else` statement and change `choice.empty?` to `choice`.

Answer (score 1):

How about Ruby's [`throw`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-throw) and [`catch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-catch) for this scenario :

```
def ask
  puts "Choose either the 'red' or 'blue' pill"
  choice = gets.downcase.chomp
  if choice == 'red'
    puts "Fasten your seatbelt dorothy 'cause kansas is going bye-bye" 
  elsif choice == "blue"
    puts "The story ends, you wake up in your bed and believe whatever you want to believe"
  else
    puts "You have to choose one"
    throw :done,ask
  end
end

catch(:done) do
  ask
end
```

Lets run the code :

```
(arup~>Ruby)$ ruby -v a.rb
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [i686-linux]
Choose either the 'red' or 'blue' pill
foo
You have to choose one
Choose either the 'red' or 'blue' pill
bar
You have to choose one
Choose either the 'red' or 'blue' pill
blue
The story ends, you wake up in your bed and believe whatever you want to believe
(arup~>Ruby)$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class WrongChoice < StandardError
end

puts "Choose either the 'red' or 'blue' pill"

begin
  choice = gets.to_s.downcase.chomp
  raise WrongChoice.new unless ['blue', 'red'].include? choice 
  if choice == red
    puts "Fasten your seatbelt dorothy 'cause kansas is going bye-bye" 
  else 
   puts "The story ends, you wake up in your bed and believe whatever you want to"
  end
rescue WrongChoice
  puts "You have to choose one"
  retry
end
```

Comment: While I wouldn't use an exception for this, the retry is very elegant.